# proxychain unable to resolve ip address

Tags: kali-linux, proxychains

I have my proxychains configured as

```
strict_chain
proxy_dns
http 172.16.20.2 3128
```

because I can access internet through `172.16.20.2:3128`. But running the proxychains gives me the following error

```
root@kali:~# proxychains apt-get update
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
0% [Working]|DNS-request| http.kali.org 
0% [Connecting to http.kali.org]|S-chain|-<>-172.16.20.2:3128-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--denied
|DNS-response|: http.kali.org does not exist
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
0% [Working]^C
```

So, what's wrong? I suspect nothing is wrong with my proxychains because it runs on tor but not on `172.16.20.2:3128`. `172.16.20.2:3128` runs fine on my browser so what prevents it from running on proxychains?

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain that you will want to comment out "strict_chain" and then remove the comment on "dynamic_chain". 
Like so..

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 4

#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted

dynamic_chain

#Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app

#strict_chain

# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
```